# How to use session in Ms-Team Application

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-teams

Im working on Ms-Team Application and in .net MVC technology when I render my application inside Ms-Team  using manifest file then session not working and session remain null
My session state is InProc mode

Comment: InProc Sessions are stored inside of application's process on web server. In this case SQLServer or Custom mode state is more suitable. Can you please share more insight about your issue, so that I can help.

Comment: Thanks 
Ive resolve issue by adding this **cookieSameSite="None"** because when application open in Iframe lax state not work